# Unable to set value of an array to 0 in a loop - JS

Tags: arrays

l have an issue with my js code where l want the value of my array to equal 0 in a loop but instead, it keeps adding or minusing on top of each-other each time it loops.

```
for(i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
  alert(players[i] + " Score is " + player_scores[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in array usage.. This is a working solution, I add some minor improvements too:

```js
var players = [];
var player_scores = [];

var num_players = 0;
num_players = prompt ("Tell me the total number of players");

for(i=0; i < num_players; i++){
    players.push(prompt("Tell me name: "));
    player_scores.push(0);

    var start_time = new Date();
    start_time.setSeconds(start_time.getSeconds() + 10 );

    for (lives=3; lives>0; lives--) {
      var guess = prompt("K _ _ G");
      var current_time = new Date();
      if (guess.toUpperCase() === "KING" && current_time < start_time) {
        alert ("Guess was correct");
        player_scores[i] += 5;
        break;
      } else if(guess.toUpperCase() === "HINT" && current_time < start_time) {
        alert ("GIVE HINT HERE");
        lives++;
        alert ("You have " + (lives-1) + " lives left");
      } else if(current_time >= start_time) {
        alert ("Time ran out");
        lives = 0;
    } else {
        alert ("Guess was wrong");
        player_scores[i] -= 2;
        alert ("You have " + (lives-1) + " lives left");
    }
  }
  alert("Player " + players[i] + "'s final score is " + player_scores[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
  alert(players[i] + " Score is " + player_scores[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `player_scores[i] = 0;` and you had to add/subtract the points for player i and not player 0: `player_scores[i] = player_scores[i] - 2;`

This works:

```js
var players = [];
var player_score = [];
var player_scores = [0];
// CHANGE THE VARIABLES //

var num_players = 0;

while (num_players <= 0) {
    num_players = prompt ("Tell me the total number of players");
}

for(i=0; i < num_players; i++) {
    players[i] = prompt("Tell me name: ");
    player_scores[i] = 0;

    start_time = new Date();
    start_time.setSeconds(start_time.getSeconds() + 10 );

    for (lives=3; lives>0; lives--) {

        guess = prompt("K _ _ G");
        current_time = new Date();

        if (guess == "KING" || guess == "king" && current_time < start_time) {
            alert ("Guess was correct");
            player_scores[i] = player_scores[i] + 5;
            break;
        }  
        else if (guess == "HINT" || guess == "hint" && current_time < start_time) {
            alert ("GIVE HINT HERE");
            lives = lives + 1;
            alert ("You have " + (lives-1) + " lives left");
        }  
        else if (current_time >= start_time ) {
            alert ("Time ran out");
            lives = 1;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Guess was wrong");
            player_scores[i] = player_scores[i] - 2;
            alert ("You have " + (lives-1) + " lives left");
        }
    }

alert("Player " + players[i] + "'s final score is " + player_scores[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
alert(players[i] + " Score is " + player_scores[i]);
}
```